# AWS Cloud9 - Screen recording

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud9-ide, aws-cloud9

Does AWS Cloud9 offer screen recording option?

I would like to record screen while doing pair programming.

Also, Is it possible to have the cloud9 editor within my web application?

Comment: There are plenty of external programs for screen recording. cloud9 does not provide build-in mechanism for that.

Comment: Is it possible to integrate both external screen recording and cloud9 so that the user doesnt have to go to 2 diff systems?